# What's happening to my label?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls

Ok so I have this code to create controls on my form:

```
public CableID_DuplicateView(CableID_CreateView CView)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Label lbl = new Label();
    Button btn = new Button();
    ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();

    if (CView.input == 1)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Please select a cable number to duplicate:";
        lbl.Location = new Point(12, 9);

        cmb.Location = new Point((lbl.Width + 17), 6);
        cmb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 20);

        btn.Location = new Point((lbl.Width + cmb.Width + 17), 5);
        btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 23);
        btn.Text = "Add to Table";

        this.Height = cmb.Height + 48;
        this.Width = lbl.Width + cmb.Width + btn.Width + 34;

        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.Controls.Add(cmb);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

    }
}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

What is causing my label to get cut off like that? And why is the comboBox sitting in a strange location?

Comment: You need to set the width, and it may be getting drawn behind the textbox

Comment: set a width on your label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that label.width is 100 which is not covering the whole text do this instead:

```
lbl.Text = "Please select a cable number to duplicate:";
lbl.Location = new Point(12, 9);
lbl.Width = 200;
```

You can also do this:

```
lbl.AutoSize = true;
```

Try this to set AutoSize width Property:

```
lbl.Text = "Please select a cable number to duplicate:";
lbl.Location = new Point(12, 9);
lbl.AutoSize = true;
this.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Width property will not be set until the control has been added to the parent container.

Comment: ok, I like the `AutoSize`. Toruble is this doesn't set the `Width` or `Size` properties, causing things to interact strangely (overlapping and such). Is there a way I can use this to set the `lbl.Width`?

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it. Though I'm not quite sure why the location of `this.Control.Add(lbl)` makes a difference..?

Comment: I told you because AutoSize will not set the width property until and unless the control is added to a parent container.

Comment: Ahh yes, because the `cmb.Location` still works of the original width of the label. Got it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You didn't set `Width` for your Label Control.so it takes some default width for your `Label`

**Solution:** You need to set `Width` for your Label

Try This:

```
lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20); //width = 200, height = 20
```

Comment: ok that did it for the label. It's not quite long enough still but I'll fix that. Thing is, the end of the text is getting cut off. Is that normal if the label isn't long enough?

Comment: @Ben: yes, if the width of the Label is not long enough then it can not show the complete text.

Answer (score 1):

As others said the width for the label is too short.

**Solution 1**: Set the width to a larger fixed width:

```
lbl.Width = 200;
```

**Solution 2**: Set AutoSize to true:

```
lbl.AutoSize = true;
```

**Solution 3**: Combine a fixed width with the AutoEllipsis property:

```
lbl.Width = 100;
lbl.AutoEllipsis = true;
```

When using AutoEllipsis the label remains the set width,
but the shown text is followed by three dots to indicate that not all text is shown.